# Is there something wrong with my CAAnimation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

Code:

```
UIView *superView = [self.view superview];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = 0.5f;
animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[root.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[superView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"removeContentAnimation"];
```

self.view and root.view were added in "superView"

When I committed this animation, there was a little chance to occur a error - Both of the views was removed from the superView and came back immediately. After this quick change, it disappeared normally.

Comment: question not very clear, what is the error? what are self.view and root.view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this doku: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

1. you cannot animate removeFromSuperView.
2. you should use blocks to animate the views

and here is a short hint:

```
- (IBAction)hideView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay: 0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
             viewToHide.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [viewToHide removeFromSuperView];
        }];
}
```